# Why does SSD resize random crops during data augmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

The SSD paper details its random-crop data augmentation scheme as:

> **Data augmentation** To make the model more robust to various input object sizes and
>   shapes, each training image is randomly sampled by one of the following options:
>   – Use the entire original input image.
>   – Sample a patch so that the minimum jaccard overlap with the objects is 0.1, 0.3,
>   0.5, 0.7, or 0.9.
>   – Randomly sample a patch.
>   **The size of each sampled patch is [0.1, 1] of the original image size, and the aspect ratio
>   is between 1 and 2. We keep the overlapped part of the ground truth box if the center of
>   it is in the sampled patch. After the aforementioned sampling step, each sampled patch
>   is resized to fixed size** and is horizontally flipped with probability of 0.5, in addition to
>   applying some photo-metric distortions similar to those described in [14].
>   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf

My question is: what is the reasoning for resizing crops that range in aspect ratios between 0.5 and 2.0?

For instance if your input image is 300x300, reshaping a crop with AR=2.0 back to square resolution will severely stretch objects (square features become rectangular, circles become ellipses, etc.) I understand small distortions may be good to improve generalization, but training the network on objects distorted up to 2x in either dimension seems counter-productive. Am I misunderstanding how random-crop works?

[Edit] I completely understand that augmented images need to be the same size as the original -- I'm more wondering why the authors don't fix the Aspect Ratio to 1.0 to preserve object proportions.

Answer (score 0):

GPU architecture enforces us to use batches to speedup training, and these batches should be of the same size. Using not-so-distorted image crops could make training more efficient, but much slower.

Comment: I completely understand that augmented images need to be the same size as the original -- I'm more wondering why the authors don't fix the Aspect Ratio to 1.0 to preserve object proportions.

Comment: I think that the only answer is to train it yourself with AR==1 and compare results :) Maybe on pixel-level, given high level of local correlation, AR 2 is really ok to learn some features from it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I consider that any transformation makes sense as long as you as a human can still identify the object/subject, and as long as they make sense in the receptive field of the network. Also I guess somehow that the aspect ratio might help to learn some kind of perspective distortion (look at the cow in fig 5, it's kind of "compressed"). Objects like a cup, a tree, a chair, even stretched are still identifiable. Otherwise you could also consider that some point-controlled or skew transforms just don't make sense as well.
Then, if you are working with different images than natural images, without perspective, it is probably not a good idea to do so. If your image shows objects of a fixed known size like in a microscope or other medical imaging device, and if your object has more or less a fixed size (let's say a cell), then it's probably not a good idea to perform strong distortion on the scale (like a cell twice as large), maybe then a cell twice as an ellipse actually makes more sense.
[With this library](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_basics.html#heavy-augmentations), you can perform strong augmentations, but not all of them make sense if you look at the image here:
[image]